# GIS different coords

Tags: geolocation

Could you, please, explain me the difference between two types of coordinates:

`[-11539.488377739675,6710096.017961704]`

and

`51.4977973,-0.2691569`

These coordinates represent London location, but they are different! Why?

Comment: Are from different CRS... search questions about geographic and proyected coordinates, there are a lot of them

Comment: The top is a projected coordinate system (likely in m),  whereas the bottom is a geographic coordinate system in degrees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second pair of coordinates is the latitude and longitude, respectively, of a point in London (represented as Y,X here - note that in many cases they would be represented as longitude, latitude as (X,Y)).  Lat/Long is a geographic system represented in degrees - as in, degrees of referenced Earth spheroid, for an angle from the centerpoint.

The first pair of coordinates is the same point (presumably), represented in a projected coordinate system.  As opposed to geographic systems (lat/long), projected systems create a flat two-dimensional projection of the Earth's surface (as the name suggests).  XY coordinates are then assigned based on position along each respective axis, based on distance (in projection system units) from a set origin point.

You have to look and see what projection the dataset or map service is using for that non-geographic coordinate pair.